# All nowhere dense sets on a discrete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Find all *nowhere dense* sets on a discrete metric space.
>
> Recall $A$ is nowhere dense if Int($\overline{A}) = \emptyset$.

Obviously, $\emptyset$ is nowhere dense in a discrete metric space. I also claim that every singleton set $\{x\}$ on a discrete metric space is nowhere dense for $x \in X$. I don't think I am finding all these sets though. Any pushes in the right direction?

Comment: If you had to guess, what would you guess?

Comment: I have been ruminating on this for a few hours. I would guess that every subset of a discrete metric space is nowhere dense.

Comment: Okay, now you'll want to check your intuitions for a couple of examples. Say if the metric space has just one element, or two elements...

Comment: Why do you "claim" that $\{x\}$ is nowhere dense? Have you proved that, or are you just guessing? By the way, what are the open sets in a discfrete metric space?

Comment: Hmmm. I have not rigorously proved it. Consider $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ where $\epsilon \in (0,1)$. Then, under the discrete metric, $B_{\epsilon}(x) = \{x\}$, which motivates me to believe that single point sets are of empty interior. For the second question, I believe all subsets are open sets in discrete metric space.

Comment: (1) Is $B_\epsilon(x)$ open? (2) Is $\{x\}$ open? (3) What is the interior of an open set? (4) What is the interior of $\{x\}$? (5) Does $\{x\}$ have empty interior?

Comment: (1) $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is open. (2) In a metric topology every single point set is closed. (3) The interior of an open set is the set itself. (4) The interior of $\{x\}$ is $\{x\}$(?) (5) Implying $\{x\}$ does not have empty interior.

Comment: Mostly right but you dodged question (2). The question was not "is $\{x\}$ closed"; the question was "is $\{x\}$ open". Is it? Next question: (6) is $\{x\}$ nowhere dense? (7) Can any nonempty open set be nowhere dense? (8) Can any nonempty subset of your discrete metric space be nowhere dense?

Comment: (2) Yes, $\{x\}$ is closed. (6) onward. I'm stumped.

Comment: In a discrete metric space, any subset $A \subset X$ is both open and closed, i.e. $Int A = A$ and $\overline{A} = A$. So, $Int(\overline{A}) = Int(A) = A \neq \emptyset$. So the only nowhere dense subset in a discrete metric space is $\emptyset$.